# Entity Framework with tree structure instead of list possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, api, red-black-tree

Okay, so I am busy writing an API for this service I am working on. Now the DB is quite huge. The client is experiencing many performance issues. Can be anywhere from 1-4 mil records (from DB) that is being worked with at a time from one customer. C# uses an `IEnumerable` list (`.ToList()`) to store data upon retrieval.

The problem with this however is that the underlying data structure is an array. Thus O(n) for main operations. Which is very slow when working with mass amounts of data and uses far to much memory and processing power.

One approach I am thinking of using to help solve this problem is by using a Red-Black tree instead of the list. As I need fast insertions and removals the RB-tree (balanced) gives guaranteed O(logn) performance.

The code for the RB-Tree is done and dusted and needs no more modification (all works well there). But is it possible for me to use this data structure instead of the list? For this I need to know what is being returned in the GET method. (How does the data look like in the list).

The table name in the database that I am working on is `AspNetUser`. The `Id` (primary key) is of type `nvarchar(128)`.

The RB tree structure:

- RedBlackTreeNode.cs (defines nodes)
- RedBlackTree.cs (defines main operations)

Stored as follows using generics: `RedBlackTree(TKey, TValue)`

Important note: using ADO.NET Entity Data Model

What I currently have:

```
//GET api/AspNetUsers
public IEnumerable<AspNetUser> Get()
        {
            using (APEntities entities = new APEntities ()) { 

                return entities.AspNetUsers.ToList(); //Is this returning the whole list with each record in the table as an entry?
            }
        }
```

How would I do the RB-Tree implementation? Like this?:

```
RedBlackTree<String, AspNetUser> RBT;

//GET api/AspNetUsers
        public RedBlackTree<String, AspNetUser> Get()
        {
            // How to iterate through each record and add to the tree structure?
        }
```

In RedBlackTree.cs

```
 public sealed class RedBlackTree<TKey, TValue>
  {
     public void Add(TKey key, TValue value){...}
     .
     .
     .
  }
```

How would each record in AspNetUsers be saved as "TValue" and the Id in AspNetUsers to be as "TKey" -For RedBlackTree(TKey, TValue).

Comment: Are the users trying to pull down millions of records at a time, or are they just working with a db with that many records? Can't the queries they're running be narrowed down? Use a where clause, page through the records a few at a time, etc.? This data structure seems to be re-writing what the database is good at (storing structured data in a manner which is easily queried) on your application's side. That might make sense if you were caching some of it, but that doesn't sound like it's what you're trying to do.

Comment: Okay so basically the users has these spreadsheets with a bunch of financial metadata in it. The data has to be pushed to the DB, but before that can be done it has to be extracted and each field validated according to the business rules. Once there, calculations with this data can be performed for which I am using database features such as queries. But the default way for c# to construct this data in the DB to an XML file that the API will send is to make use of a list. Which is very inefficient and I am trying to get around that. (Note in the Get method the .toList() function.

Comment: @Necoras for the previous comment

Comment: Why not pare it down to just the data you care about for any given call with an IQueryable rather than a List? That way you can minimize the data which moves over the wire. Unless the slowdown is before it ever gets into the database?